# How to correctly create a self-signed certificate for ktor server and configure https?

Tags: jvm, ssl-certificate, keytool, ktor

I want the connection to my **ktor** server to support https connection. To configure, I used the article from the documentation https://ktor.io/docs/ssl.html.
After the above steps, I get an ssl **error** when accessing the server on port **8443**

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:130)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:358)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:287)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:204)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:736)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:691)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:506)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:482)
> at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:679)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslEngine.unwrap(JdkSslEngine.java:92)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkAlpnSslEngine.unwrap(JdkAlpnSslEngine.java:163)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:297)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1353)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1246)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1295)

`application.conf`

```
ktor {
    deployment {
        port = 8080
        sslPort = 8443
    }
    application {
        modules = [ com.example.ApplicationKt.module ]
    }

    security {
        ssl {
            keyStore = keystore.jks
            keyAlias = sampleAlias
            keyStorePassword = 316853
            privateKeyPassword = 316853
        }
    }
}
```

`'main.kt'`

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = EngineMain.main(args)

fun Application.module() {
    routing {
        get("/") {
            call.respondText("Hello, world!")
        }
    }
}
```

**I created a self-signed certificate with the following command**
`keytool -keystore keystore.jks -alias sampleAlias -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -keysize 4096 -validity 3 -dname 'CN=localhost, OU=ktor, O=ktor, L=Unspecified, ST=Unspecified, C=US'`

*I also tried to export the certificate and install it in the trusted list in the **OS(**Win 11**)**, but even after that the error did not disappear (the computer restarted)*

What did I do wrong in my steps and how can I fix it?

Comment: How did you install the certificate in the trusted list?

Comment: first I exported the certificate with the following command `keytool -exportcert -alias sampleAlias -keystore keystore.jks -file certificate.crt`
Then I went into the **mmc.exe utility (Windows)** and imported the certificate into the list of user and computer, it was displayed in the list as a **localhost**